# Why does my PWD variable not retain its value?

Tags: bash

I have the following code:

```
 PWD="$(pwd)"
 echo $PWD
 cd
 echo $PWD
```

If I run this from within `/home/USER/sandbox`, the output of the above is:

```
 /home/USER/sandbox
 /home/USER
```

Why does `PWD` not preserve its value? Is there any way to get it to preserve its value?

Comment: It does... Are you sure that's exactly the code you are using?

Comment: I had actually used PWD instead of WD. When changing to WD, its fine. Doesn't work at all if the variable is named PWD. Why would that be?

Comment: because `$PWD` is a shell variable that is set every time you change directory, in general best not to use uppercase variable names.

Answer (score 1):

The key is that you called the variable **`PWD`**.  This is one of several all-uppercase names used specially by Bash:

> ### `PWD`
>
> The current working directory as set by the `cd` command.

After each `cd` command, `$PWD` is updated to match.

I recommend you use lower-case for your variable names, to avoid surprises like this.

Answer (score -1):

If I type all of those commands into the command line, I find that WD does "preserve it's value".

However I've run into this issue multiple times with various scripts and the root cause is one shell session (and/or a script) doesn't transfer its environment to another.  Common solutions include doing everything I want to do in one script and saving values in a file for later use.

Hope this helps.